# Ubuntu 17.10, PlayOnLinux, Wine v2.22, Office 2010, p11-kit: couldn't load module

Tags: wine, 17.10, playonlinux, microsoft-office

Under Ubuntu 17.10, I have had Office 2010 running on PlayOnLinux, Wine v2.22, for some months. Out of nowhere this morning – I probably haven’t tried to open it for a week or so – I get the following error when trying to open Word:

```
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and found that the folder `pkcs11` exists in a different place in `/usr/lib` so I made a symlink to it and, voilà, it works again.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11
```